# I have a tabbed view and how can I trigger the view to run some code with the view is actived by tabbed view?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have an app with 2 tabbed view, I wish to execute some code in the view controller when the user change the view by the tab control.  Any method I can call in the view control like viewDidAppear or something?

Thank you very much for you help.

Comment: `viewWillAppear:` and `viewDidAppear:` seem to be the best candidates for such things. Just override one of them in your view controller with the code you need to execute.

Comment: These methods are not called only by user's selecting tabs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a delegate of your tab bar view controller, and implement `tabBarController:didSelectViewController:` method.